# AngularJS repeating input radio sets

Tags: angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get AngularJS to repeated sets of the same type of input radio fields.

Example:

```html
<form>
     <ul id="group1">
         <li><input type='radio' name='optionRadio'></li>
         <li><input type='radio' name='optionRadio'></li>
     </ul>
     <ul id="group2">
         <li><input type='radio' name='optionRadio'></li>
         <li><input type='radio' name='optionRadio'></li>
     </ul>
</form>
```

AngularJS I have:

```html
<form name='testForm'>
    <ul ng-repeat='field in fields' ng-form='subForm'>
        <li><input type='radio' ng-model='subForm.optionRadio' name='optionRadio'>field.name</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The problem is when I click the radio button, it will deselect the the radio in another group.

I know the issue is name = optionRadio, but I'm trying to take advantage of $invalid from the form testForm.

If I remove name='optionRadio', I loose track of which form item needs to be highlighted for errors.

I also tried doing separate form tags, but I was having troubles with ng-repeat and form tags.

I also tried appending **$index** to the **name**, but the form object takes in the value literally.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/207/

I've made a jsfiddle.  I found a solution, that will work, but won't make use of the form validation.

I can get the same result of having an error message, by checking if the model has a value.  The other option is to write a custom directive for validation, then check the sub form for the specific error I'm looking for.

Example:

```html
 <input radioCheck type='radio' name='optionRadio'/>
 <span ng-show='subForm.$error.radioCheck'>Radio check error</span>
```

Comment: Can you post your model structure for fields? Created a plunkr for messing around but my ul gets repeated and my outputted html structure differs.

Comment: I second the previous comment. No way to give advice on this without knowing what the "fields" structure is.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using $invalid property on the model controller you can use the $invalid property on the form controller. i.e. change `<span ng-show="subform.inputRadio.$invalid">Error!!!! missing stuff</span>` to `<span ng-show="subform.$invalid">Error!!!! missing stuff</span>`

I ran into a similar problem with a custom directive I wrote to display validation classes when using nested repeats. The custom directive couldn't use the input name because they cannot be dynamic, so this wouldn't work:

```html
<ul validation-class-for="choice">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in question.choices">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{choice.text}}"
                   ng-model="$parent.response.choices" required/>
            {{choice.text}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with this custom directive:

```js
angular.module('ngQuestionnaires.validationClassFor', [])
    .directive('validationClassFor', function () {
        return {
            require: '^form',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes, formController) {
                var hasError = 'has-error',
                    hasSuccess = 'has-success';
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    var controller = formController[attributes.validationClassFor] || formController,
                        state;
                    if (controller.$invalid && controller.$dirty) {
                        state = hasError;
                    } else if (controller.$valid && controller.$dirty) {
                        state = hasSuccess;
                    }
                    return state;
                }, function (newState, oldState) {
                    switch (newState) {
                    case hasError:
                    case hasSuccess:
                        element.removeClass(oldState).addClass(newState);
                        break;
                    default:
                        element.removeClass(hasError).removeClass(hasSuccess);
                        break;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I fixed the problem by using a nested form, removing the name attribute from the radio input, and removing the value from validation-class-for, like this:

```html
<ul validation-class-for ng-form="choiceForm">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in question.choices">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="{{choice.text}}" 
                   ng-model="$parent.response.choices" required/>
            {{choice.text}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The only change required to the link function in the custom directive was a fallback to the form controller if the model controller was undefined within the scope $watch function, like so:

```js
controller = formController[attributes.validationClassFor] || formController
```